# "-bash: grunt: command not found, successful installation"

Tags: bash, terminal, gruntjs

I'm learning grunt and seem to run in a bit of problem within the terminal. When I run a grunt command, I get:

-bash: grunt: command not found, successful installation

My bash_profile reads

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export NVM_DIR="/Users/colette/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

and .bash reads

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

I don't see anything with grunt and I'm wondering whats missing if anything.

Edit

I'm now getting

```
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Not sure if it's related to my previous problem. It's also weird because I used the npm to install grunt.

Update:

Hmmmm...I had to run nvm again for it to work. But I'm still having a problem with grunt

Comment: How did you install grunt? What does `command -v grunt` say?

Comment: npm install -g grunt-cli

Comment: command -v grunt doesn't show anything

Comment: grunt -v displays (-bash: grunt: command not found)

Comment: What was that "successful installation" bit of message from? Does `npm ls` list grunt?

Comment: What does `which grunt` tell you? Perhaps you should `chmod u+x "$HOME/.rvm/bin/grunt"`?

Comment: Sorry, "successful installation" was not part of the message. I just forgot to delete it while writing my post. npm ls does list grunt@0.4.5

Comment: which grunt doesn't run anything. It just shows the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem through this walkthrough
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps

I was missing the PATH for grunt in the .bash_profile.

Not sure if I should create a new post, but I now have another question.

Why do I have to run nvm every time I start terminal? Is there a way to just have it ready to go without having to nvm install [version number]?